# playframework routes file with get parameter id and action method not working

Tags: playframework

I was looking at this example in the section "Assign static args"

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/routes

but it makes no sense as they call render(page) instead of render(id).  Maybe it is not a good example for my use case......

I have the following route...

```
GET {company}.${envDomain}/dashboard    Dashboard.dashboardPage
```

but I get an error that says the following path is not found:

```
GET {company}.dev.xxxxxxx.com/dashboard
```

The interesting thing is that it says `"GET /dashboard"` is not found and in my url I see a http://dev.xxxx.com/dashboard INSTEAD of the {company}.dev.xxxx.com/dashboard that should be there....

Why is route reversal not working?

My source code for dashboardPage is such.

```
public static voi
```

Comment: Hi Dean, looks like your question was truncated somehow, your controller source is only listed as "public static voi" which I assume isn't right ;) Also, can you paste in your full routes file

Comment: Also, what do you mean with `but it makes no sense as they call render(page) instead of render(id). Maybe it is not a good example for my use case......`? It does make perfectly sense ;-) . I tried answering this part too, but I might have gotten your question wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible via a feature implemented in Play 1.1 ([Virtual Hosts](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/releasenotes-1.1#routeHost)).

Just ensure that when you do reverse routing you are using `'@@{}'` instead of `'@{}'`, as the example shows.

Comment: the @@ was a big help and ended up being part of the issues...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**edited after learning from OP's comment about undocumented feature**

<strike>As far as I know you cannot use domain-related parameters in the routes. 
They only concern the `Request path`</strike>

Apparently there is something about the host in the [play.mvc.Router class](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/1.2.x/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java). It's still unclear to me thou..

The rest of my answer is still a feasible workaround... though not very dynamic I admit.

What you are trying to do <strike>has to</strike> could be done at a frontend level... eg. with nginx catch the subdomain and translate it to a path with a redirect. Then in your routes you can do:

```
GET /dashboard/{company}/
```

About `render` (though that would almost be a different question):

When you call `render(param)` with a String as a first parameter, it will go and load the template `param`. When `param` is anything else, it will make that variable available to the template...

Comment: no, they have specific code about using params in the hostnames but no examples and I read that it was in the release notes but not in the docs as well at some point so they DO have it and it is half working for me right now(some parts work and some don't).

Comment: @DeanHiller interesting.. and, as often with play, totally undocumented. Indeed I see something about hostPattern in the [play.mvc.Router class](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/1.2.x/framework/src/play/mvc/Router.java), towards the end. But I admit it's totally unclear.